# shell_exec() doesn't change qdisc in linux

Tags: php, linux, shell-exec

For my project I am creating WEB interface to control QoS in Linux. I am trying to communicate with terminal with shell_exec() function PHP. And it works if try something simple like this:

```
shell_exec("ip link show");
```

But if try to change qdisc with(works in terminal):

```
shell_exec("sudo tc qdisc replace dev eth0 root pfifo");
```

nothing happens. I don't get any output either if I try to echo shell_exec(...);

I am running Ubuntu 14.04. I already added line in sudoers file to execute shell commands without password:

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

%www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /var/www/html
```

Maybe I did something wrong with sudoers file or is there any more things I should do before running shell_esec commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /var/www/html
```

This sudoers line would only allow `www-data` to execute the file `/var/www/html`. (Which is probably a directory, not an executable file, so it doesn't do anything.)

If you want to allow `www-data` to execute `tc`, you'll need to specify that in the sudoers file, using the full path to the executable.

Comment: Changed it to `%www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/php/ajax.php`, but still get same errors.

Comment: @Ignotas It should be somehting like `%www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/tc` where you replace `/usr/bin/tc` with the actual path to the `tc` program.

Comment: ANSWERED. Sudoers line has to be `www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/tc` and shell-exec line - `shell_exec("sudo tc qdisc replace dev eth0 root pfifo");`

Answer (score 1):

It's not the exact answer, but try like this. It worked for me.

`2>&1` produces the error message.

```
if(exec("sh  whatever your cammand 2>&1", $output, $return_var))
{
    print_r($output);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: It returns:
    `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`
If I try without sudo:
   `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted`
So I guess it still asks password.

Comment: How does this solve the problem with `sudo` permissions?

Comment: It doesn't, but it helped me see errors of failed shell commands.